# Scrape Table Data Into Dataframe

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

An example URL is 'http://www.hockey-reference.com/players/c/crosbsi01/gamelog/2016'

The table name I am trying to grab is named Regular Season.

What I use to do in previous instances was something like this...

```
import requests
from bs4 import *
from bs4 import NavigableString
import pandas as pd


url = 'http://www.hockey-reference.com/players/o/ovechal01/gamelog/2016'
resultsPage = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resultsPage.text, "html5lib")
comment = soup.find(text=lambda x: isinstance(x, NavigableString) and "Regular Season  Table" in x)
df = pd.read_html(comment)
```

That's the type of approach I took to a site similar to this one, however, I'm unable to locate the table properly with this page.  Not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one table which you can get using the id:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'http://www.hockey-reference.com/players/o/ovechal01/gamelog/2016'
resultsPage = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resultsPage.text, "html5lib")
table = soup.select_one("#gamelog")
print(table)
```

or using just pandas:

```
 df = pd.read_html(url, attrs = {'id': 'gamelog'})
```

Your code could never work as you are looking for a *NavigableString* which is inside a caption tag *`<caption>Regular Season  Table</caption>`* not the table, you would need to call `*`.find_previous`* to get the table:

```
comment = soup.find(text=lambda x: isinstance(x, NavigableString) and "Regular Season  Table" in x)
table = comment.find_previous("table")
```

You could also use `table = comment.parent.parent` but find_previous is a better approach.